# How should I set my partitions on a system with one small SSD and one large HDD

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, filesystem, ssd

Before ditching windows I enjoyed very short boot times because my OS and mission critical programs were all installed on my solid state, while my music, videos, recordings, and video games were on my hard disk drive. I wanted to have a similar setup when I moved to ubuntu and put /usr/ and /home/ on my HDD and everything else on the SSD. I now suffer from longer boot times.

Was putting /home/ and /usr/ on my hdd a mistake? Should I have only done /usr/local and made symlinks to there from my home folder?

Comment: Partitioning for the most part is a personal choice. I personally like `/home` and `/` on my SSD, I also prefer my swap on the mechanical, along with `/opt`, and maybe `/var` or `/usr` depending on my needs.

Answer (score 1):

For Home/Work PC:

1. `/home` on **HDD**
2. swap on **HDD**
3. `/` on **SSD**
4. `/tmp` in **ramfs**

Comment: Was my mistake mounting /usr/ to the HDD? I'm thinking there's some configuration files somewhere the computer is waiting on before booting and I don't know what is up. I've asked in other places on the internet and someone told me there were lots of config files hidden in the /home directory i need on startup for 16.04 but i'm not sure what they were talking about.